# SVN revert from within a NAnt script?

Tags: svn, nant, nant-task

I thought this would be a simple task, but I'm currently unable to get it to work. There are built in functions such as `<svn-update>` etc. But not for revert it seems?

I have tried using the following but get an error that I have no supplied enough parameters.

```
<svn command="revert" destination="${root}" uri="${build.repos}" username="${build.user}" password="${build.pwd}"></svn>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by using the following -

```
<svn command="revert" destination="${root}" uri="${build.repos}" username="${build.user}" password="${build.pwd}">
    <arg line="-R"/>
    <arg line="revert"/>
    <arg line="${root}"/>
</svn>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [generic **svn** command](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc2/help/tasks/svn.html) where you can specify any command including **revert**:

```
<svn command="revert" ... />
```

Comment: That is the one I have tried and noted in my question, but it seems to not be working? Can't seem to find any documentation that indicates what parameters I need to pass.

Comment: 1) What exception/error do you get back? 2) Here is the link for documentation: http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc2/help/tasks/svn.html

Comment: "svn: Not enough arguments provided"

I had previously found that documentation, thanks. But it only contains generic information for the SVN task, not it's usage for each command, i.e. revert.

Comment: This seems to be coming from SVN itself, not from the NANT task.

Comment: Which SVN version do you use?

Comment: Have you tried executing command line version of SVN to revert?

Comment: Using version 1.5 of subversion. Revert from the command line works fine.